# Mostrar query con id del usuario actual en Django

Tags: django, django-views

Quisiera que me muestre los cursos por usuario. Necesitaría que realizara lo siguiente pero con el id del usuario que inicie sesión, ya que ahorita el código me muestra los exámenes en general y me falta agregarle el id, y no sé cómo agregar el id del usuario que está utilizando el sistema.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM quiz_course c WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM quiz_result r, testing_testing t WHERE r.exam_id = c.id and t.id = 3);
```

Views: (esta parte del codigo es la que necesito corregir `and t.id = id`)

```
@login_required(login_url='testinglogin')
@user_passes_test(is_testing)
def testing_exam_view(request):
    con = MySQLdb.connect(user='root', db='dataevaluat', passwd='', host='localhost')

    with con:
        cur = con.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM quiz_course c WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM quiz_result r, testing_testing t WHERE r.exam_id = c.id and |t.id = id|;")

        courses = cur.fetchall()

        for c in courses:
            print(c)

    return render(request, 'testing/testing_exam.html', {'courses': courses})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La información del usuario que inicia sesion vive en el objeto request de tu funcion como lo indican en la documentacion de Django [User authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests)

Siguiendo esa premisa puedes modificar tu codigo de la siguiente manera:

```
@login_required(login_url='testinglogin')
@user_passes_test(is_testing)
def testing_exam_view(request):
    con = MySQLdb.connect(user='root', db='dataevaluat', passwd='', host='localhost')
    user_id = str(request.user.id)
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        query = "SELECT * FROM quiz_course c WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM quiz_result r, testing_testing t WHERE r.exam_id = c.id and |t.id = " + user_id + "|;"
        cur.execute(query)

        courses = cur.fetchall()

        for c in courses:
            print(c)

    return render(request, 'testing/testing_exam.html', {'courses': courses})
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me funciono la corrección